# Postgres full text search not working for some terms

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-12

I am using Postgres FTS to implement search. This is my sample `tsvector`:

```
{'analyst':2A 'busi':1A}
```

The query I am using is

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE tsv @@ to_tsquery('english', 'b:*')
```

The result is showing correctly, but if I use `'a:*'` instead of `'b:*'`,

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE tsv @@ to_tsquery('english', 'a:*')
```

The result is an empty set.

Is this some bug in PostgreSQL serach? I am using PostgreSQL version 12.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'a' is a stopword, and to_tsquery removes it even if it already decorated with ':*'.  I don't what the rationale for that is, it is not very intuitive to me.

So you will have to avoid the use of to_tsquery.  You could instead do `'a:*'::tsquery`.

Answer (score 3):

'a:' isn't a valid lexeme in English:

```
SELECT to_tsquery('english', 'a:')
```

> NOTICE:  text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain
> lexemes, ignored